# Assign group name to kivy graphic instruction

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

This seems like it should be really simple, yet I have failed to find a way to do it.

In order to iterate over the instructions on my canvas, I am supposed to use `canvas.get_group()` method. In order to do that, I first need to assign a group name to whichever instructions I intend to iterate over. How does one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer to my own question which I was able to find.

So, i have found ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230958/how-do-i-reference-ids-of-children-within-a-canvas-in-kivy)) that Instructions (and many other classes in the canvas scope) have a `group` property, not listed in the documentation, which can be set when creating the instruction:

like so in python:

```
with self.canvas: (self must be a widget)
    Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size, group='my_group')
```

and like so in kv:

```
<SomeWidget>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            group:'my_group'
```

When done like so, a later call to `self.canvas.get_group('my_group')` returns an iterable with the instructions in it.

However this has its own problems. Check my [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476837/return-from-canvas-get-group-call-in-kivy).

Answer (score 0):

Use `InstructionGroup()`. This is an example from kivy documentations:

```
blue = InstructionGroup()
blue.add(Color(0, 0, 1, 0.2))
blue.add(Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(100, 100)))

green = InstructionGroup()
green.add(Color(0, 1, 0, 0.4))
green.add(Rectangle(pos=(100, 100), size=(100, 100)))

# Here, self should be a Widget or subclass
[self.canvas.add(group) for group in [blue, green]]
```

Comment: I have tried this. But calling `get_group()` with the group varialbe name assigned (`canvas.get_group('green')` for example) yields no instruction in the resulting iterable, i.e., returns an empty list. I am looking for a way to assign a group name so I ca use it in a `get_group()` call.