# Return from canvas.get_group() call in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Calling `get_group()` from an instruction group yields back more that what I wanted.

I have the following code:

```
for widget in self.selected:
    dx, dy = (
        widget.pos[0] - self.pos[0],
        widget.pos[1] - self.pos[1]
    )
    self.shadows.add(Rectangle(size=widget.size, pos=widget.pos, group='my_shadows'))

self.canvas.add(self.shadows)

print self.shadows.get_group('my_shadows')
```

which in turn produces the following result:

```
<kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture object at 0x7ff992377050>
<kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle object at 0x7ff99493e638>
<kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture object at 0x7ff9923770e8>
<kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle object at 0x7ff99493e6e0>
```

What are BindTextures and why are they returned through `get_group()`? I expected only Rectangles.
If i intend to manipulate my Rectangles, do I need to do the same with my BindTextures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you've already noticed that with `Rectangle` you can set a background image of a Widget. That's what [`BindTexture`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.BindTexture) is for as it provides `source` parameter for a path to an image that can be used as a background.

If you don't intend to use those Rectangles as background images (from file, not drawing with `Color` + `Rectangle`), I think it is safe to ignore the textures.

Comment: I am working on a simple drawing app. This is part of the select box for selection of objects on the designer screen. My intention was to use the rectangles as shadows for the selected objects to be move around before moving the actual object. I would only mess with postioning and sizing. It worked great for a single object, but trying to do this for multiple selection is starting to look like a bad idea. Seems it would be simpler to think of widgets instead of canvas instructions